How to test the Android Nearby connection in Android studio?
I am using the Android Nearby Connection APIs; docs here. I have set up two AVDs and I tried different examples from https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main, but I cannot pair my two AVDs.
I found some articles pointing out that the Emulators cannot simulate Bluetooth, is that the reason why I cannot pair the two virtual devices?
Is there any solution to test the nearby connection APIs without multiple physical Android devices?
